# how to get digits recognize from digital weighing scale using OCR?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to extract decimal digits from the digital weighing scale, I am able to generate a mask image but am not able to extract digits from it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("input.png")

# Color-segmentation to get binary mask
lwr = np.array([43, 0, 71])
upr = np.array([103, 255, 130])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
cv2.imwrite("/Users/ahx/Desktop/msk.png", msk)

# Extract digits
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
cv2.imwrite("/Users/ahx/Desktop/res.png", res)

# Displaying digits and OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(''.join(t for t in txt if t.isalnum()))
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr8Gx.jpg)

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6NMu.png)

Can anyone please help how can I print the result from the output(mask)image?

Comment: its better to share input also

Comment: Try by output image invert color.

Comment: @AlexAlex thank you. I have tried but it's not working. I am facing issue with digital digits, is there any other way to solve this problem?